# Kotlin how to set tablayout inside fragment (viewpager is not working)

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to create `tablayout` inside fragment. for some reason my `viewpager` is not working properly. it keep showing same error as below

[image]

my fragment codes and xml files are below

```
package com.example.rsquare_android_fixed.mywork.building

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.rsquare_android_fixed.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_mywork.*


class MWFragment: Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mywork, container, false)

        Log.d("test","test")

        //vp_main.adapter=MW_Adapter(childFragmentManager)
        val fa=MW_Adapter(childFragmentManager)
        vp_main.adapter=fa
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(vp_main)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mywork, container, false)
    }

}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:theme="@style/TabTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="hi"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> but if i try same codes on mainactivity it works well ...

Comment: please post your code add in side of question. please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sry didn't know that. i fixed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that kotlin's extension is not yet aware of your fragments view
since it calls `getView` internally to find views in the fragment which returns `null` at the point where you're using
Try using `vp_main`  in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView`

Answer (score 0):

Your are using layout element before initialize. In `onCreateView()` you are accessing element before `inflating view`.

You can move your code **val fa .. to tab_layout** code in `onCreatedView()` or in `oncreateView()` first inflating view reference it to a variable then initialize your `tab_layout`,`vp_main` by reference `view`. then return it.